# How to remove value from hidden field using jquery.autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I have a page with two inputs: `users_list` and `users_ids`. jquery.autocomplete is used to autocomplete the `users_list`. `users_ids` is hidden field. When the user is selected and added to the `users_list` his id is added to the `users_ids`. Everything works fine. But the question is how to remove the value from `user_ids` if the user is removed from `users_list`?

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function formatItem(row) {
      return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
    }
    function formatResult(row) {
      return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
    }
    $("#users_list").autocomplete("<%= url_for(:controller => :users,
                                               :action => :autocomplete_users_list) %>",
    {
      multiple: true,
      matchContains: true,
      mustMatch: true,
      autoFill: true,
      formatItem: formatItem,
      formatResult: formatResult
    });

    $("#users_list").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
      var hidden =  $("#users_ids");
        hidden.val( (hidden.val() ? hidden.val() + ";" : hidden.val()) + data[1]);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question has nothing to do with jquery autocomplete... You want to remove an item from a serialized array. So:
Your hidden field value is like this: id;anotherid;onelastid
So the code would be:

```
function remove_id_from_hidden(id) {
    var hidden =  $("#users_ids");
    var arr = hidden.val().split(";"); # transforms the string into an array
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(id), 1); # removes the item from the array
    hidden.val(arr.join(";")); # sets the value again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hiddenfield where i stored the ids of the selected values.

In order to catch when there is no value, and the users has removed a value i use:

```
$('input.autocomplete').blur(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) < 1) {
        $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(0);
    }
});
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete(/* autocomplete code */);
```

the blur event catches when users moves focus from autocomplete input box and sets hiddenfield to 0, independently of what autocomplete does.